# Is it possible to get access_token using cookie in asp.net core?

Tags: angular, asp.net-identity, restful-authentication, openiddict

when user logs in using external login it creates a cookie but i want to use token instead , is it possible with openiddict or any other method? there is method available as below but dont know how to use it.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken()
            {
                var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
                var Token = await 
               // whats pupose and provider should i use ?
                _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(User,provider??,purpose??);
                if (user == null) return Ok("No user - not logged in");// if Authorize is not applied
                return Ok(Token);
            }
```

Comment: Nope, there's (deliberately) no way to generate a token from your own code. Here's the recommended approach: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34809639/542757.

Comment: @Pinpoint hi thanks for reply , i am getting error confidetial client can have only response type=code even if i set it to public , 2.

Comment: the JS client app, with the token appended to the URI fragment. where is it?

Comment: @Pinpoint is there any way to skip authorize page , not proper to ask everytime

Comment: You can add `prompt=none` to your authorization request to renew the access token. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/36064475/542757 for more information.